# Retrieving mocked object name in mockito in

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, junit4

So I am using doAnswer() API to mock a method setProperty(String,String) of the Node class

```
Node attachmentsJcr = mock(Node.class);        
doAnswer(AnswerImpl.getAnswerImpl()).when(attachmentsJcr).setProperty(anyString(),anyString());
```

AnswerImpl is implemented below-

```
public class AnswerImpl implements Answer{

    private static AnswerImpl instance;

    private AnswerImpl(){
    }

    public  static AnswerImpl getAnswerImpl(){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new AnswerImpl();
            return instance;
        }
        else
            return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {

        final String key = (String)(invocationOnMock.getArguments())[0];
        final String value = (String)(invocationOnMock.getArguments())[1];
        final String mockedObjectName = ? 
        results.put(key,value); // results here is a hashhmap
        return mockedObjectName;
    }
}
```

I was able to retrieve the arguments that was passed to the setProperty method. 
But I am unable to retrieve the mockedObjectName("attachmentsJcr" in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mocked objects do not have "names". The only reason for a mock object to exist is to allow you to **control** the behavior that your code under test "sees" when interacting with mock objects injected into it.

In other words:

```
Node attachmentsJcr = mock(Node.class);
```

does **not** create a "real" Node object. Yes, `attachmentsJcr` is a reference to a Node object; but this object was "magically" created by the mocking framework. It doesn't have the "real" properties of a Node object. It only allows you to call the **methods** that a Node object would offer.

In that sense: if your Node class has a method like `getName()` ... then the returned name is simply that which you configured to mock to return upon calls to getName().

And just to be sure: AnswerImpl is not "production code", is it?

Comment: Thanks Ghost....I guess I can configure the mock objects to return a specific name when getName() is called. This should work for me. And no its not a production code.I was just playing around with mockito for learning purpose :)